# Explain the program flow in this C++ function

Tags: c++

I wrote a strange function to find the factorial of a number

```
int strange_fact(int n=0)
{
    static int i=n;
    static int j=i;
    if(j>1)     
    {       
        i *= --j;
        strange_fact();         
        return 0x7777;    //<------ This line
    }
    else
        return i;
}
```

When I commented the 9th line, I was getting the expected output. But I encountered a strange (or maybe not so strange) behaviour after adding that line. What happens when I uncomment it is that program flow reaches line 9 even though a recursive function call precedes it. My question is, how does flow reach line 9?

Comment: Hm... iiuc the innermost call in the call stack will return after j recursions (which is 1 here). At that point "this line" will be executed in the innermost recursion, at the bottom of the call stack, with the other calls still pending.

Comment: If `J <= 1` the recursive function call returns immediately and control passes to your strange line.

Comment: The fact that your program didn't immediately crash with a **stack overflow** error indicates it is returning from the recursive function at some point.

Comment: Recursive calls don't magically end the original call. Once the recursive call is complete, your program will continue where it left off, just as it would with any function call...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When recursive call to function ends, line 9 will be reached. See this (shorter) example:

```
int foo(int i) {
    if(i > 0) {
        foo(i-1);
        return 0x7777;
    } else {
      return i;
    }
 }
```

So when calling foo(1) it will go through first if (because 1 > 0) and foo(0) will be called. Now inside this call (foo(0)) program will go into else barnch (because 0 is not > 0) and foo(0) will return 0. So now we will be back to our first call (foo(1)) and as foo(0) returned, foo(1) will return 0x7777.

Comment: Thanks! Though I know that concept, it just flew away from my mind. Thanks everyone (you, @EdHeal and @gldraphael) for your answers. +1ed all answers!

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 strange_fact();
```

does the recursion and throws away the result.

The next next line

```
return 0x7777;
```

will return that value finally.

If you remove that line and compiled with the warnings on it will inform you that all paths do not return a value

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how recursions work.

After calling `strange_fact()` you've put a return statement. Meaning once the function is executed, it's still going to return `0x7777`, which screws the answer up.

Check this out, this should work as expected:

```
int strange_fact(int n=0)
{
    static int i=n;
    static int j=i;
    if(j>1)     
    {       
        i *= --j;
        strange_fact();         
        // return 0x7777;    // We don't want to return a value yet
    }
    if(j<=1)          // We need to check this condition after strange_fact is executed
        return i;

    // This line will never be executed
    return 0x7777;    //<------ This line
}
```

If you eliminate the static variables, you'll get something like this:

```
long fact(long i)
{
    if(i > 0)
        return i * fact(i-1);
    if(i == 0)              // factorial(0) = 1
        return 1;

    throw exception("Negative numbers cannot have factorials"); // Or you can handle it by returning a -ve error code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The whole thing, explained by a diagram

Let us consider the case of `strange_fact(3)`

[image]

So, whatever happens in the recursive steps becomes meaningless because ultimately, `0x7777` will be `return`ed when the control comes back to the first call.